# Hibernate: Why does the index column update only when inverse="false"

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, dao

Good day folks:

Please, look at my xml mappings:

### `User.hbm.xml`

Especially look at `inverse="false"` and `<index column="EVENT_INDEX" />`   :

```
<hibernate-mapping package="demidov.pkg.domain">
    <class name="TheUser" table="USER">
        <id name="userId" column="ID" type="integer">
            <generator class="native"/>         
        </id>

        <property name="userFirstName" column="FIRST_NAME" type="string" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="userLastName" column="LAST_NAME" type="string"/>
        <property name="userEmail" column="EMAIL" type="string" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="personAddress" column="PERSON_ADDRESS" type="string" />
        <property name="personPhoneNumber" column="PERSON_PHONE" type="string" />
        <property name="userGender" column="GENDER" type="string"/>

        <list name="userEventsList" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all" >
            <key column="USER_ID" not-null="true" />
            <index column="EVENT_INDEX" />          
            <one-to-many class="UserEvents"/>       
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### `UserEvents.hbm.xml`

Especially look at  `<many-to-one name="theUser" class="TheUser" insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="save-update">`

```
<hibernate-mapping package="demidov.pkg.domain">
    <class name="UserEvents" table="USER_EVENTS">
        <id name="userEventId" column="ID" type="integer">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="userEventDate" column="EVENT_DATE" type="date"/>
        <many-to-one name="theUser" class="TheUser" insert="false" update="false" lazy="false" fetch="select" cascade="save-update">
            <column name="USER_ID" not-null="true"/>
        </many-to-one>

        <joined-subclass name="ComputerMaintenanceEvent" table="MAINTENANCE_EVENT">
        <key column="MAINTENANCE_ID" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="descriptionMaintenance" column="DESCRIPTION_MAINTENANCE" type="string"/>
            <property name="additionalInfoMaintenance" column="ADDITIONAL_INFO_MAINTENANCE" type="string"/>
        </joined-subclass>              

        <joined-subclass name="SoftwareDevelopmentEvent" table="DEVELOPMENT_EVENT">
        <key column="DEVELOPMENT_ID" not-null="true"/>
        <property name="descriptionDevelopment" column="DESCRIPTION_DEVELOPMENT" type="string"/>
        <property name="additionalInfoDevelopment" column="ADDITIONAL_INFO_DEVELOPMENT" type="string"/>
        </joined-subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

So since in my `User.hbm.xml` is `inverse="false"` and in my `UserEvents.hbm.xml` is `insert="false" update="false"` When I want to save user + userevents to my database my `<index column="EVENT_INDEX/>` will get updated and I will have index counting on elements from the collection (0, 1, 2 and so on). 
Like this:

```
+----+------------+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| ID | EVENT_DATE | USER_ID | EVENT_INDEX | MAINTENANCE_ID | DESCRIPTION_MAINTENANCE | ADDITIONAL_INFO_MAINTENANCE |
+----+------------+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | 2013-10-31 |       1 |           0 |              2 | Description maitnance   |  Maitnance Test             |
|  2 | 2013-10-31 |       1 |           1 |              2 | Description maitnance   |  Maitnance Test             |
+----+------------+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

But when I have in my `User.hbm.xml` is `inverse="true"` and in my `UserEvents.hbm.xml` is `insert="true" update="true"` and want to save user + userevents to my database, my `<index column="EVENT_INDEX/>` in the database will have `null` values for each element of inserted collection.
Like this:

```
+----+------------+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| ID | EVENT_DATE | USER_ID | EVENT_INDEX | DEVELOPMENT_ID | DESCRIPTION_DEVELOPMENT | ADDITIONAL_INFO_DEVELOPMENT |
+----+------------+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | 2013-10-31 |       1 |        NULL |              1 | Develop                 | Development Test            |
|  2 | 2013-10-31 |       1 |        NULL |              1 | Develop                 | Development Test            |
+----+------------+---------+-------------+----------------+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

And another problem why my hibernate insert-copy same values that many times that my collection elements included. As you could see from tables I am trying to save to DB one DESCRIPTION_DEVELOPMENT and one DESCRIPTION_MAINTENANCE object -> they are in one collection , but hibernate save them twice because I have 2, BUT DIFFERENT elements in same collection.

How I insert:

```
List<UserEvents> eventList  = new ArrayList<UserEvents>();

SoftwareDevelopmentEvent sde = new SoftwareDevelopmentEvent();
sde.setDescriptionDevelopment("Develop");
sde.setAdditionalInfoDevelopment("Development Test");
sde.setUserEventDate(new Date());
eventList.add(sde);

ComputerMaintenanceEvent cme = new ComputerMaintenanceEvent();
cme.setDescriptionMaintenance("Description maitnance");
cme.setAdditionalInfoMaintenance(" Maitnance Test");
cme.setUserEventDate(new Date());
eventList.add(cme);

TheUser user = new TheUser();
user.setUserFirstName("Vadim1");
user.setUserLastName("Dem1");
user.setUserGender("Male1");
user.setUserEmail("vad@mail.ru");
user.setPersonAddress("Adress");
user.setPersonPhoneNumber("1111111");

user.setUserEventsList(eventList);

dao.saveUser(user);
```

DAO method is simple:

```
public void saveUser(TheUser user) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.save(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my post here.

[Java - Hibernate @ManyToMany mapping adds records in the database only in one direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644045/java-hibernate-manytomany-mapping-adds-records-in-the-database-only-in-one-di/19644571#19644571)

You need to set both side of the relationship.

e.g. cme.setUser(user);

Alan